Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS Lag After Waking from Suspend
I'm having some issues with my Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS running on a Thinkpad P15v AMD Ryzen 5 pro 6650h and NV167 (dual booted with W11. Two Separate SSDs). My laptop becomes significantly laggy after waking up from suspend particularly after closing the laptop's lid. Everything is laggy including inputs and the laptop battery consumption is noticeably high. This is also affecting wifi. Rebooting brings things back to normal but I'm not sure what is happening.
I recently updated to the latest Ubuntu version and started noticing these issues. I ran the following command:
dmesg -l warn

and these are the output messages that I get. Has anyone experienced this and could you help me find a solution? Thank you!
[    0.338556] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP11: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S4) by S0 from power resources
[    0.342945] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP12: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S4) by S0 from power resources
[    0.353050] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP19.NHI0: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S3) by S0 from power resources
[    0.356087] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.GP19.NHI1: Overriding _PRW sleep state (S3) by S0 from power resources
[    0.560333] pnp 00:05: disabling [mem 0xffffffe0-0xffffffff] because it overlaps 0000:01:00.0 BAR 6 [mem 0xfff80000-0xffffffff pref]
[    0.827286] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    0.827418] platform eisa.0: EISA: Cannot allocate resource for mainboard
[    0.827420] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 1
[    0.827422] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 2
[    0.827424] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 3
[    0.827426] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 4
[    0.827427] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 5
[    0.827429] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 6
[    0.827431] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 7
[    0.827433] platform eisa.0: Cannot allocate resource for EISA slot 8
[    1.140600] r8169 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.582414] block nvme1n1: the capability attribute has been deprecated.
[    1.609474] systemd[1]: Configuration file /run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessible via APIs without restrictions. Proceeding anyway.
[    2.608486] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.GPP0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20230628/nsarguments-61)
[    2.832051] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: [drm] No compatible format found
[    2.920616] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Enhanced Setup Synchronous Connection command is advertised, but not supported.
[   15.238989] kauditd_printk_skb: 51 callbacks suppressed
[  112.028471] kauditd_printk_skb: 35 callbacks suppressed
[  149.613238] warning: `ThreadPoolForeg' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[  731.005998] kauditd_printk_skb: 2 callbacks suppressed
[ 5777.575378] workqueue: acpi_ec_event_processor hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
[54743.368760] ACPI: button: The lid device is not compliant to SW_LID.
[54743.432580] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[54743.432596] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 18360 at kernel/workqueue.c:1794 __queue_work.part.0+0x30c/0x3e0
[54743.432650] Modules linked in: tls ccm michael_mic rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common snd_soc_dmic snd_soc_acp6x_mach snd_acp6x_pdm_dma snd_sof_amd_acp63 snd_sof_amd_vangogh snd_sof_amd_rembrandt snd_sof_amd_renoir edac_mce_amd snd_sof_amd_acp snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_ctl_led snd_sof kvm_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_sof_utils kvm snd_soc_core snd_hda_intel snd_compress irqbypass snd_intel_dspcfg ac97_bus qrtr_mhi crct10dif_pclmul snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_pcm_dmaengine polyval_clmulni binfmt_misc amdgpu qrtr joydev snd_pci_ps polyval_generic snd_hda_core snd_rpl_pci_acp6x ath11k_pci ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep sha256_ssse3 nouveau snd_acp_pci uvcvideo btusb sha1_ssse3 snd_acp_legacy_common snd_seq_midi ath11k btrtl aesni_intel videobuf2_vmalloc mxm_wmi snd_seq_midi_event uvc btintel crypto_simd amdxcp qmi_helpers snd_pci_acp6x videobuf2_memops btbcm cryptd drm_gpuvm videobuf2_v4l2 nls_iso8859_1 drm_buddy
[54743.433218]  snd_rawmidi btmtk drm_exec snd_pcm rapl input_leds mac80211 gpu_sched drm_suballoc_helper videodev snd_pci_acp5x bluetooth drm_ttm_helper snd_seq videobuf2_common thinkpad_acpi think_lmi ttm snd_rn_pci_acp3x ecdh_generic serio_raw firmware_attributes_class wmi_bmof mc nvram k10temp ecc snd_seq_device snd_acp_config drm_display_helper cfg80211 snd_soc_acpi snd_timer cec snd_pci_acp3x libarc4 rc_core snd i2c_algo_bit mhi soundcore ledtrig_audio mac_hid amd_pmf amdtee ccp amd_sfh tee hid amd_pmc platform_profile acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul psmouse thunderbolt i2c_piix4 nvme xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas nvme_core r8169 nvme_auth realtek rtsx_pci ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec video wmi i2c_scmi
[54743.433812] CPU: 4 PID: 18360 Comm: kworker/u24:53 Not tainted 6.8.0-40-generic #40~22.04.3-Ubuntu


there is no version 24.04.5 yet. The latest version is 24.04.1 Running Windoze alongside Ubuntu has long been an issue. Disable Faststart on Windows 11 to see if there is an improvement

Thank you, I'll disable faststart on W11. I just double checked my Ubuntu version and I am running 22.04.5, but I see that one of my tags and Title say 24.04 so I will update that. Thank you

I have a simillar issue on my zbook:

I suspend the laptop.
Switch of power -> on battery
Switch on power -> on mains again.
Return from suspend.

=> Laptop is often very slow, close to useless
I have the following workaround:

Put it on battery
Put it on power.

=> Again at full speed.
